# reentry to uk when you have overstayed your visa

Tags: visas

i have been living in uk on an expired visa since 2013, during which time my old usa passport (on which i entered the uk) expired and, therefore, i have a new one -- i need to go to the states for a family emergency -- will i have a problem to return?

Comment: Almost certainly yes.

Comment: BTW you are staying illegally on UK. By giving advice you want to hear, you can cause trouble for us. Please do not ask us to explain you how to do illegal things.

Answer (score 5):

You are currently overstaying in the UK. The UK authorities will deport you if they find out and they will deny a new entry if you try to come in again and if they recognize your status.

You seem to hope that your new passport will wipe the slate clean, but the UK has records from an [Advance Passenger Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance_Passenger_Information_System) system if you came by air, rail or ferry.